# How to make Qicon fill entire QTableWidgetItem or grid in QTableWidget

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, qtablewidget

I have worked on QTableWidget,the question is how to make a Qicon to fill in the entire grid or QTableWidget in QtableWidget,even stretch with width or height of the grid,thank you.
[image: running result]
[image: picture 1.png]
[image: picture 2.png]
[image: picture 3.png]

Code as below:

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import QIcon

class Table(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Table, self).__init__()
        self.initUI()
    def initUI(self):
        self.setWindowTitle("QTableWidget Example")
        self.resize(400,300)
        self.layout=QHBoxLayout()
        self.TableWidget=QTableWidget(2,3)

        self.TableWidget.setHorizontalHeaderLabels(['Nmae','Sex','Weight(kG)'])

        self.newItem=QLineEdit('Jack')        
        self.TableWidget.setCellWidget(0,0,self.newItem)        

        self.newItem=QLineEdit('Male')        
        self.TableWidget.setCellWidget(0,1,self.newItem)        
        self.newItem=QLineEdit('160')        
        self.TableWidget.setCellWidget(0,2,self.newItem)     

        self.newItem=QTableWidgetItem(QIcon("./icon/1.png"),'')
        self.TableWidget.setItem(1,0,self.newItem) 

        self.newItem=QTableWidgetItem(QIcon("./icon/2.png"),'')
        self.TableWidget.setItem(1,1,self.newItem)

        self.newItem=QTableWidgetItem(QIcon("./icon/2.png"),'')
        self.TableWidget.setItem(1,2,self.newItem)
   

        self.layout.addWidget(self.TableWidget)

        self.setLayout(self.layout)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app=QApplication(sys.argv)
    win=Table()
    win.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: I see you're setting header labels for all columns, but then you're also setting items for the header: the result is that the labels for those columns will be overwritten (or, better, *cleared*). Is your intention to only show the streched image, or do you also want to show the section text above it? Also, your question is a bit confused anyway: do you want to stretch the icons to fill the section, or the entire header?

Comment: Sorry for make confuse,my intention is to stretch image/icon to fill the entire section not header,  now I modified the code, please help to check again, thank you.

Comment: Are those actual images with some specific content, or are you trying to draw a color that fills the entire cell?

Comment: Yes these images purpose to fill entire cell as three types, include entire fill with green, fill the front half with green and fill the back half with green,I think can't finish this task by filling the cell so I draw 3 different pictures for each purpose

Comment: I voted to reopen as the OP also requires stretching of the image, while the duplicate answer will result in keeping the original aspect ratio of the image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use an [*item delegate*](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/model-view-programming.html#delegate-classes), then check if the index has valid data for the *decoration role* and, in that case, draw it instead of using the default painting function.

```
class ImageDelegate(QStyledItemDelegate):
    def paint(self, painter, opt, index):
        decoration = index.data(Qt.DecorationRole)
        if decoration is not None:
            if isinstance(decoration, QIcon):
                decoration = decoration.pixmap(opt.rect.size())
            # decoration role can also contain a QColor, we only want a pixmap
            if isinstance(decoration, QPixmap):
                painter.drawPixmap(opt.rect, decoration)
                return
        super().paint(painter, opt, index)


class Table(QWidget):
    # ...
    def initUI(self):
        # ...
        self.delegate = ImageDelegate(self.TableWidget)
        self.TableWidget.setItemDelegate(self.delegate)
```

Comment: This is exactly what I need, thank you very much